# How to get a field that only exists in one Crystal subreport to show in other subreports

Tags: crystal-reports, ssms

I am taking over a report that was created by someone else that consists of the main report and 7 subreports. One of the subreports has a numeric field (OTHER_TIME_INT) that I need to get in all of the subreports. My issue is that the option only exists in this one subreport and I cannot figure out where the field is coming from.

How do I get this field from one subreport to all of the subreports if it is not in my main report?

Also - the report is populated by a command statement created in SSMS. The OTHER_TIME_INT is being defined as integer in the original sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Data found in subreports goes out of scope once the subreport has been printed.  To get around this you will need to use a global variable.  Here are the basic steps to creating the global variable.

On the subreport where the data exists you will need to create a new formula field.  You can name it whatever you want, but for this answer I will call it `GetVariable`.  Here is the formula you will want to enter for this formula field.

```
Shared NumVar otherTime;
otherTime := {OTHER_TIME_INT}
```

The first line initializes a variable named `otherTime` with a datatype of NumVar, while the second line assigns it a value from a field on the subreport.  The Shared keyword indicates the scope of the variable.  There are 3 different scopes for variables in Crystal Reports, these are Local, Global, and Shared.  Local variables are only usable within the formula they are created, Global variables may only be used within the scope of the main report document (no subreports), and Shared variables may be used throughout the main report and all of its subreports.

Place the `GetVariable` formula field into the subreport where your `{OTHER_TIME_INT}` field is displayed, then edit the format properties of the `GetVariable` formula field so that it is suppressed and not visible on the subreport.

Any place where you would like to retrieve this variable will now require a new Formula Field as well.  For example, if you have a second subreport where you need the value of this variable you will want to create a new formula field in that subreport.  Again the name of the field can be anything you want, but for this example I will call it `GetValue`.  The formula for this field will be:

```
Shared NumVar otherTime;
otherTime;
```

Again, the first line creates the variable with the name `otherTime`.  It already has a value from before, so there is no need to assign one.  The second line prints the value of the `otherTime` variable.

This is a pretty basic example of how to pass a value from one subreport to another using a variable, but I would also recommend you look up a good tutorial on using variables in Crystal Report for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Important caveat: to display a shared variable value from a subreport, the formula in a main report must be located in a section below the subreport section...